# Brownian motion: exit time from symmetric strip

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to figure out why my way of thinking is not valid.

Consider a Wiener process $W_t$ and the strip $S_a = [-a/2,a/2]$ with $a$ positive. I'm wandering what is the probability $P_a(t)$ that the process has never left the strip?

So I thought that:

$$
P_a(t) = Prob\{|x(\tau)|\le a/2, \forall \tau \in [0,t]\}
$$

could be re-written as:

$$
P_a(t) =Prob\{ M_t \le  a/2 \cap m_t \ge -a/2, \forall \tau \in [0,t]\} 
$$

where: $M_t=max\{W_s | 0 \le s \le t\} $ and: $m_t=min\{W_s | 0 \le s \le t\} $. Now I see those two events (the one involving the maximum and the one involving the minimum) as independent events, so i can write:

$$
P_a(t) =Prob\{ M_t \le  a/2, \forall \tau \in [0,t]\} * Prob\{m_t \ge -a/2, \forall \tau \in [0,t]\} 
$$

I think that something stated above is already wrong, because, when I compute it, it turns out to be something like:

$$
P_a(t) \sim erf(1/\sqrt{t}) - erf^2 (1/\sqrt{t})
$$

where $erf$ is the error function. From the last one (with all the factors) it turns out that the expected value of the exit time is infinite, nor $a^2/4$ as I would expect (I'm referring to: *An informal introduction to Stochastic Calculus with Applications - Ovidiu Calin*, pg. $83$, exercise $4.3.9$).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please use `* *` for nice *italics*, not mathjax.

Comment: Is the question about the proability of particles modelled by a weiner process never leaving the strip? It's the bit where it says the *process* never leaves the strip. I guess it must be.

Comment: "...with a positive." - with a positive what, charge (mind :-) )? Is there physics in the missing word.

Comment: So you want to do it your way (from relatively simple principles) - you are not interested in using the standard time dependent probability density function for such a process?

Comment: the distribution is only gausian in the temporal limit, you haven't defined the initial distribution as  you only consider one particle, you haven't specified even its initial position $x(0)$ although we can assume it is intended to be 0.

Comment: @JMLCarter My bad: $x(0)=0$.  If I use the standard time dependent probability density function I would just have $P_a(t) \sim erf(a/4\sqrt{t})$ right? But then the expected value of the exit time $T$ is still infinite since it's given by an integral between $0$ and $\infty$  of $e^(-1/T) /\sqrt{T}$, so I still cannot obtain the result $a^2 /4$. What is missing?

Comment: The integral of a probability distribution over all space = 1, not infinity?

Comment: We should be looking for this. Plus
The expectation as t tends to infinity is 0. (The system is not expected to move)

Comment: $e^0=1$ , divided by infinity from $\sqrt{T}$ gives 0. The distribution tends to zero in the limit. The integral up to time T should be finite. The integral up to infinity tends to a limit, as the function will be 0 in the limit.

Comment: Ok let me write it down explicitly: so: $P_a(t) \sim erf(a/4 \sqrt{t})$ so the probability of the time $T$ of exit from $S_a$ is $=1-P_a(t)$ , so the probability density function of $T$ is $\sim e^{-1/T}/\T^{3/2}$. Now: $$E[T]\sim\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-1/T}/\sqrt{T} \, dT$$ from which I get the divergence. I thought that this is the expected value of the first exit time, but, as the reference I reported in the question is saying, this expected value should be $a^2/4$.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: agreed the problem seems to be a maths problem.

Comment: I will post there. Thank you very much @JMLCarter

Comment: Of course, $M_t$ and $m_t$ are not independent hence the argument falls flat. By the way, the joint distribution of $(M_t,m_t)$, and by consequence the distribution of $T_a$, are well known but the densities are most often expressed as series, due to the reflection principle.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of not walking over max includes paths that walked below the min. By symmetry the probability of walking below the min includes paths that walked above the max.

(Consider rolling a 6 sided dice. The probability of rolling a 3 or 4 is 1/3. 
If you multiply the probability of rolling a 1,2,3 or 4 by that of rolling a 3,4,5 or 6, you will get 2/3*2/3 which is 4/9, which is different.)

I think you should compute

$$
P_a(t) =1-((1-Prob\{ M_t \le  a/2, \forall \tau \in [0,t]\}) + (1-Prob\{m_t \ge -a/2, \forall \tau \in [0,t]\}) 
$$

this is the probability that's left cutting away the probabilities of exceeding each limit.

Comment: "The probability of not walking over max..." yes, of course! But you're saying like I considered the $or$ logic condition  (i.e. $\cup$) between the events involving the max and min, but I didn't do so; so why are my equations wrong? Please also take a look at my comment to my question.

Comment: No you have done an *and*. 
Your A*B, which is A and B, is the same as if you tried to calculate the probability of two particles, one particle being in A *and* the other particle being in B. 
(A could be outside the region of B, and B could be outside the region of A.)
If you can see that's what it means, you can see it isn't what you wanted. If you try to interpret it for a single particle it's difficult.

Comment: I know that I've done an $and$ , and that is what I was trying to say in the last comment :) I don't see the similarity with the two particles case; I'm considering *the same* $W_t$ when I write $M_t$ and $m_t$ , so I'm considering the same particle such that the maximum of its spatial coordinate is less than $a/2$ *and* the minimum is more than $-a/2$.

Comment: It's the same as your other answer from zero. I'll try think of another way to explain it.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that... I think that now I get it.. So the minimum and the maximum, as I wrote them down, are evaluated for *eventually* (right?) two different realization of the same Wiener process, so it's like considering (*eventually* :P) two different particles.

Comment: Errm ...well  I came up with this question for you.
If I have *any* two unknown sets A and B and I know P(A) and I know P(B), do I know anything about the size extent or membership of the intersection between A and B (or the probability of being in it)?
The answer is I hope clearly not. It could be a large intersection or a small one.

Comment: If you accept that you - can see that an expression for $P(A\cap{B})$ cannot be formed in terms of P(A) and P(B), could it. What's needed is info on the regions  A and not B or on the region B and not A.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have spotted the flaw in your argument. The problematic piece is $\forall \tau\in [0,t]$. For any $\tau \in [0,t],M_t\leq a/2$ and $M_t\geq -a/2$ are not independent events. This is because given that $M_t\leq a/2$ is true (say), we now know that $Prob(M_t> a/2)=0$, and so all the unconditional probability (for $M_t> a/2$) gets reassigned over the interval $M_t\leq a/2$, which then also changes the probability for $-a/2\leq M_t\leq a/2$ in general.

------------------Previous answer-------------------------

I don't know stochastic calculus, so the supposed mistakes I have spotted in your argument may not actually be.

$|x(\tau)|<a/2$ is not logically equivalent to $(M_t\leq a/2~\cap~m_t\geq a/2)$. I am not sure what a Wiener process is, but first condition is about a range of values for $x$, while the latter seems to be only about two particular values. Probability measure over those conditions, as far as I can see, cannot be the same.

Comment: $x(\tau)$ is the realization of the stochastic process $W_t$. Thanks, however, for your reply :)